# OnTextChanged EditorFor c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

hola tengo un `EditorFor` y necesito que cuando este vacío me llene una lista

```
<div class="input-group b-r-xl">
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Buscar, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Busqueda por asunto, numero o fecha", value = "
  <?=$_POST['var']?>" } })
    <div class="input-group-btn">
      <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="model.Buscar" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <?=$_POST['var']?>" es de PHP, ¿Estás seguro que es C#?

Comment: Si te fijas está dentro de un par de comillas: `value = "  <?=$_POST['var']?>"`, aunque realmente no creo que tenga mucho que ver...